# Update Keyclock Access token

Tags: keycloak, keyserver

What are the possible ways to update the current access token or provide a new access token to users When I add new information to the keylock jwt tokens? 
 Ex: When I add a new role to the specific user that not include in the current access token.

Answer (score 2):

You need to request new tokens (access, refresh, id) the same way as you did it the first time. You cannot update existing token.